# rpy2 - how to save dataframe as RData file to disk?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am wondering how to save a pandas dataframe to an `.RData` file, How can I save to an RData from from a pandas dataframe?  I have everything up to the last step here:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

# load RData file
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(robjects.r['get'](robjects.r['load'](path_to_rdata_file)))

.... do some processing to df ...

# save df as RData file
r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
??????????
```

How can I save the pandas data to disk as an `.RData` file?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out the answer, here is how you write to `.RData` file using a pandas dataframe:

First convert dataframe to R dataframe:

```
r_data = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
```

Then we have to assign the dataframe to a variable in the "R workspace":

```
robjects.r.assign("my_df", r_data)
```

Finally, we can reference the variable by name in order to call the `save` command:

```
robjects.r("save(my_df, file='{}')".format(filename))
```

> Here are 2 helper functions if you want to read/write RData files but work in python with pandas:
>
> ```
> # read .RData file as a pandas dataframe
> def load_rdata_file(filename):
>     r_data = robjects.r['get'](robjects.r['load'](filename))
>     df = pandas2ri.ri2py(r_data)
>     return df
>
> # write pandas dataframe to an .RData file
> def save_rdata_file(df, filename):
>     r_data = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
>     robjects.r.assign("my_df", r_data)
>     robjects.r("save(my_df, file='{}')".format(filename))
>     os.chmod(filename, 0o777)
> ```